# CSS Footer not at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

i have this CSS for my footer:

```
/* FOOTER */
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:580px;
    border-top:4px solid #666666;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
#footer-inner {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    height:inherit;
}
#footerTop {
    width:100%;
    height:480px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:2px #000000 solid;
}
#footerTopLeft {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
#footerTopMid {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
#footerTopRight {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
}
```

i need there to be no gap at the bottom of the page but there is about half an inch gap for some reason

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mYqS3/1/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/mYqS3/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `#footerTop` change `margin-top` to `padding-top`

```
#footerTop {
    width:100%;
    height:480px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom:2px #000000 solid;
}
```